# RxJava race condition on IO

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

**PROBLEM**

I'm trying to logout my user when one of the API calls end up as failed due the lack of authorization token. But I cannot manage to sync operations on `Schedulers.io()` with `SharedPrefs.commit()`. All the calls are made at the same time and as a result all of them try to log out at the same time.
What I want to achive is to have only first one to trigger the logout and remaining two to notice, that it happend and not trigger anything at all.

**CONSTRUCTION**

I've got 3 API calls that autohrize with a token.
The token is held inside `SharedPrefs`. 
All of the API calls are made on `Schedulers.io()`.
When the token refresh failure is called I'm trying to remove data from my `SharedPrefs` with logout method.

Below is the logout method code:

```
 Flowable.fromCallable { isUserLogged() }
            .filter { it }
            .flatMap { logoutUseCase.execute() }
            .doOnComplete { showLogin() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .blockingSubscribe()
```

This method is called inside `Authenticator` class connected to `OkHttpClient` working with `Retrofit`

Comment: I don't think rx can help you with synchronization unless you're willing to have call 2 & 3 happen after call 1. `SharedPrefs` is supposedly thread safe, but it has a different lock for both reading and writing. Since you're doing a write->read, I suggest you wrap your logout code with your own lock in some kind of `LoginManager`.

Comment: I would recommend rethinking your implementation. If you are encountering a race condition while using Rx, then you are using Rx incorrectly. Try to take a step back and rethink what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @WoogieNoogie the problem is not in RxJava. Problem is that async calls made by RxJava(correct ones and desired) all comunicate with one part of application that is not synchronized and as a result all of them have outdated info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem in quite easy way.
Since `Authenticator` is only triggered when -

> authentication challenge from either a remote web server or a proxy server

occures, therefore I can synchronize the part of my code responsible for refreshing my token. This way whenever a refresh token failure occurs the `logout()` method will be synchronized and the data in each of the calls updated.

**CODE**

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route, response: Response): Request? {
    synchronized(this, {
      ###refresh token code###
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Observable.amb()` operator to resolve the race.

If each API call emits an error when there is no authentication token, then you can organize them so:

```
Observable.amb( apiCall1Observable, apiCall2Observable, apiCall3Observable )
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .doOnError( error -> {
    logoutUseCase.execute()
   } )
  .subscribe( value -> {
   },
   error -> {
   });
```

The `amb()` operator will select the first one to issue a value or termination event. That will trigger the `logoutUseCase.execute()` which will only be performed once.

The key is to refactor the status from your individual API calls, pushing the decision about when and where to do the logout to a higher level.

Comment: Well that's not the case I don't have the scope to check api calls since all of the checking happends inside authentication part of the call iteself.
Only for this example I have 3 calls but there are parts of the application that have 2, 4 or just one. The result code must be much more flexible.
Thanks for help tho.